# Making form with entries using a loop in perl Tk

Tags: loops, perl, tk-toolkit

I have the following code in which I am making a form where I want to enter multiple timesteps, lat, and longitude entriess as shown below:

```
my $mw = MainWindow->new;

my $exec_frame2 = $mw->Frame()->pack(-side => "top");
my $title_frame_track = $exec_frame2->Frame()->pack(-side=>"top");
$title_frame_track->Label(-text => '')->pack(-side => "top");
$title_frame_track->Label(-text => 'Storm Coordinates/Track')->pack(-side => "top");


my $frame1 = $exec_frame2->Frame()->pack(-side=>"top");
$frame1->Label(-text => 'Time Step:')->pack(-side=>"left");
my $timestep1 = $frame1->Entry(-width => 15)->pack(-side =>"left");
$frame1->Label(-text => 'Lat:')->pack(-side=>"left");
my $lat1 = $frame1->Entry(-width => 5)->pack(-side =>"left");
$frame1->Label(-text => 'Lon:')->pack(-side=>"left");
my $lon1 = $frame1->Entry(-width => 5)->pack(-side =>"left");
$frame1->Label(-text => 'Max Wind:')->pack(-side=>"left");
my $maxwind1 = $frame1->Entry(-width => 5)->pack(-side=>"left");

my $frame2 = $exec_frame2->Frame()->pack(-side=>"top");
$frame2->Label(-text => 'Time Step:')->pack(-side=>"left");
my $timestep2 = $frame2->Entry(-width => 15)->pack(-side =>"left");
$frame2->Label(-text => 'Lat:')->pack(-side=>"left");
my $lat2 = $frame2->Entry(-width => 5)->pack(-side =>"left");
$frame2->Label(-text => 'Lon:')->pack(-side=>"left");
my $lon2 = $frame2->Entry(-width => 5)->pack(-side =>"left");
$frame2->Label(-text => 'Max Wind:')->pack(-side=>"left");
my $maxwind2 = $frame2->Entry(-width => 5)->pack(-side=>"left");

my $frame3 = $exec_frame2->Frame()->pack(-side=>"top");
$frame3->Label(-text => 'Time Step:')->pack(-side=>"left");
my $timestep3 = $frame3->Entry(-width => 15)->pack(-side =>"left");
$frame3->Label(-text => 'Lat:')->pack(-side=>"left");
my $lat3 = $frame3->Entry(-width => 5)->pack(-side =>"left");
$frame3->Label(-text => 'Lon:')->pack(-side=>"left");
my $lon3 = $frame3->Entry(-width => 5)->pack(-side =>"left");
$frame3->Label(-text => 'Max Wind:')->pack(-side=>"left");
my $maxwind3 = $frame3->Entry(-width => 5)->pack(-side=>"left");

MainLoop ;
```

This code is supposed to create a image like this:

[image: Desired form]

Is there a way to make put the variables frame, timestep, lat, lon and maxwind into arrays so that I can put the code above into a loop?  I attempted to do condense the first set of code into a looop below but got an error.

```
for (i=0,i<10;i++)
{
    $frame[$i] = $exec_frame2->Frame()->pack(-side=>"top");
    $frame[$i]->Label(-text => 'Time Step:')->pack(-side=>"left")
    $timestep[$i] = $frame[$i]->Entry(-width => 15)->pack(-side =>"left");
    $frame[$i]->Label(-text => 'Lat:')->pack(-side=>"left");
    my $lat[$i] = $frame[$i]->Entry(-width => 5)->pack(-side =>"left");
    $frame[$i]->Label(-text => 'Lon:')->pack(-side=>"left");
    my $lon[$i] = $frame[$i]->Entry(-width => 5)->pack(-side =>"left");
    $frame[$i]->Label(-text => 'Max Wind:')->pack(-side=>"left");
    my $maxwind[$i] = $frame[$i]->Entry(-width => 5)->pack(-side=>"left");   
}
```

Is there anyway to tweak this code to get the desired result and keep the code more concise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalar variables in Perl have to start with a dollar sign. Declaring a variable is also a good habit:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
```

There's also a semicolon missing after the `$timestep[$i]` assignment. Moreover, [my](https://perldoc.pl/my) shouldn't be used for array elements, e.g.

```
my $lat[$i] = ...  # Wrong!
```